# installing nominatim on CentOS 8: could not file postgresql (missing: postgresql_library postgresql_include_dir)

Tags: linux, postgresql, installation, nominatim

I installing nominatim on a CentOS8-System and i get an error at installing nominatim

```
cmake $USERHOME/Nominatim-3.5.1
```

like this

```
-- Building osm2pgsql 1.2.0
-- Building in C++11 mode
-- Boost version: 1.66.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
CMake Error et /usr/shar/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardApps.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find PostgreSQL (mitting: PostgreSQL_LIBRARY
  PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

The path to /usr/pqsql-12/bin is set in then .bach_profile and is loaded.
PostgreSQL and PostgreSQL-devel is installed.

What can i do to solve this problem. I'm not a Linux-Poweruser an need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use cmake3 instead cmake

you have to install cmake3 by

```
yum install cmake3
```

Answer (score -1):

I found if I edited the file

```
/usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPostgreSQL.cmake
```

and added "12" to this list of versions here ...

```
PostgreSQL_KNOWN_VERSIONS
```

.. then cmake worked.